# Calling a javascript file from a batch script

Tags: javascript, batch-file

Okay, so I have one batch script which I want to run on start-up without opening the command window, so I wrote a JavaScript file which does this, but the computer I want to run it on doesn't run JavaScript files on start-up, but it does run batch files! So my question is:

-Is it possible to call a JavaScript file from a batch script, and how?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to install [node.js](http://Nodejs.org)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mozillas Rhino: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino

You can use the js scripts from batch like you would do with python ones

```
$ rhino file.js
```